# How to retrieve the data from database and display in pdf format in java

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, pdf, jdbc

1. I want to display the data which are stored in the database in a pdf file format
2. I have displayed in web page, instead of that I want to display in pdf. Below is my code, i used a MySQL database

---

```
public class StockReceiptReturnQuery extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String receiptNo = request.getParameter("ReceiptNo");
        int Rno = Integer.parseInt(receiptNo);

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "root", "dinga");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from project.stockreceiptreturn WHERE ReceiptNO =?");
            ps.setInt(1, Rno);
            out.print("<center><table width=25% border=1></center>");
            out.print("<center><h1>StockReceiptReturnQuery:</h1></center>");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            /* Printing column names */
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            while (rs.next()) {
                out.print("<tr>");
                out.print("<td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(1) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getInt(1) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(2) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(3) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(3) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(4) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(4) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(5) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(5) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(6) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(6) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(7) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getInt(7) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(8) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getInt(8) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(9) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(9) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(10) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getInt(10) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(11) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(11) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(12) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getDouble(12) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(13) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getDouble(13) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(14) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getInt(14) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(15) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getInt(15) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(16) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getDouble(16) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(17) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getDouble(17) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(18) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getDouble(18) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(19) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getDouble(19) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(20) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(20) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(21) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getInt(21) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(22) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(22) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(23) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getInt(23) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(24) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getInt(24) + "</td></tr>");

            }
            out.print("</table>");

        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

- I am getting out put after running pgm

[image]

Comment: @halfer,@Sam please help me out to solve the problem

Comment: You can only notify one person per comment... And I'm not sure what you mean by PDF format, but your code looks like it's writing HTML

Comment: @ cricket_007,yes i did in Html i want to print in pdf file .

Comment: Here you go: a code example on how to do it with iText: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/html-tables

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using some sort of pdf generator library, this will allow you to create a PDF in the style you like with your data.

An example of a library from doing a Google search is PdfBox https://pdfbox.apache.org/ however feel free to use your own.

The general approach you do is create a Pdf document programatically and fill it with your data. There should generally be ways to style the Pdf in a format that you want (implementation will depend on which library you use).

You will need to save the file somewhere (whether on your server or on a cloud platform) to allow the user to download the pdf. Then present the download link to the user on the webpage.

Comment: You could provide a code sample instead of a link, no?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11633404)

Comment: @cricket_007 code depends on the library you choose to use.

Comment: @Teepeemm provided some extra information in the new edit. Also PdfBox is by Apache, so while the page conten may change change I think the library will be around for a while

Comment: So your answer to "how do I create and display a pdf?" is create a pdf and present it to the user?  How does that help OP?

Comment: @Teepeemm The answer is to use a library to create one, save it on your server and present the link to the user. There's a few parts to it. "How do I create a pdf" would be a follow up question, or "how do I create a table in a pdf using library x", so would "how do I store and present a file to a user using Framework X" 
My answer gives the user somewhere to start going from. There's plenty of answers on stack overflow that tell you how to create a table in a pdf, I'm not going to duplicate it here.